# Tokenizing math expression with functions in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, tokenize

I figured this would be easy to find, but I haven't been successful.

I need to be able to tokenize the following expression

> (4 + 5) + myfunc('two words', 3, 5)

into

```
(
4
+
5
+
myfunc
(
'two words'
,
3
,
5
)
```

It seems like this is probably a common need, however I haven't been able to find any good documentation on this out there.  Is this something I could do using regex?  Anybody know of an existing way to do this?

I'm using C#, but if you have the answer in another language, don't be shy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to use a [lexical analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

Comment: refer ["State of the Art Expression Evaluation"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18880/State-of-the-Art-Expression-Evaluation)

Comment: So just to be clear, you are looking for a tool like antlr (http://www.antlr.org/) rather then NCalc (https://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking into a robust and powerful solution, you should definitively look into a lexical analyzer (like Antlr). However if what you need is just tokenization of simple expressions like the one you provided, you can achieve this result pretty easily:

```
// TODO Refactor and optimize this function
        public IList<string> TokenizeExpression(string expr)
        {
            // TODO Add all your delimiters here
            var delimiters = new[] { '(', '+', ')', ',' };
            var buffer = string.Empty;
            var ret = new List<string>();
            expr = expr.Replace(" ", "");
            foreach (var c in expr)
            {
                if (delimiters.Contains(c))
                {
                    if (buffer.Length > 0) ret.Add(buffer);
                    ret.Add(c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    buffer = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer += c;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Example:

> TokenizeExpression("(4 + 5) + myfunc('two words', 3, 5)") Count = 14
>
> ```
> [0]: "("
> [1]: "4"
> [2]: "+"
> [3]: "5"
> [4]: ")"
> [5]: "+"
> [6]: "myfunc"
> [7]: "("
> [8]: "'twowords'"
> [9]: ","
> [10]: "3"
> [11]: ","
> [12]: "5"
> [13]: ")"
> ```