# Tokenizing a expression string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, expression

I have a calculation formula string of the form

```
 string formula = w_tb + Min(d_3,a_x) * Pow(x,2)
```

In the above example `w_tb, d_3, a_x, x` are variables. I am able to find the list of variables in the formula by splitting the strings using the operands as the delimiter.

But in order to assign the values to the variables (value from the database), my first approach was to replace the variable name with the value of the variable from the database. But that would result in replacing even a substring of the expression string with the value. Eg : If the variable x is replaced with the value 1,2 in the expression string a_x will be replaced to a_1,2 which is not the required result.

I have the list of variables and and the complete list of delimiters(operators).

What I am trying to achieve?

I am trying to get the following list from the expression string

```
List<string>() {"w_tb","+","Min","(","d_3",",","a_x",")","*","Pow","(","x",",","2",")"}
```

Is there a way I could achieve the task.

I have already tried the solution mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424251/5243291) answer. But the tokenizer I am having is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called Parsing, frequently used by compilers.

You can define a simple grammar for your expression and let a parser-generator generate the parser code for you. It allows you to define syntax errors and gives the full token list like the one you want. A very good example in Antlr. Have a look http://www.antlr.org/

Comment: I am unable to think of a grammar that would suffice my need. :(. But in no way i am looking fro someone to write a grammar for me. but an approach to do so.

Comment: The answer you linked in your question looks simple and good. You can use it.

Comment: yes. But it applies only if the delimiter is a char array. In that case i loop through all the characters in the string and achieve my intended result. in my case the delimiter is a string array. I could do this again by looping through all characters , appending it as a string and searching for delimiter substring in it and adding it to string after some string manipulations. but it isnt as convenient as it should be. and the chances of failure are really high.

Comment: @Vini You would simply need a tokenizer. It would break up the expression into singular tokens, which you can then properly replace and re-combine. For example, your expression might have the tokens `w_tb, Min, d_3, a_x, Pow, x, 2` (of course, `Min` and `Pow` might be classified as 'function-tokens' which can be excluded from the replace process)

Comment: Note that Antlr (as Kilanny recommended) will provide this functionality for you. The grammar file I would imagine would be extremely simple (almost to the point of `token: [a-z]+(0-9)*` with a few edge cases for method calls, etc.

Comment: @Rob: I will try writing a grammar; but probably that is going to result in another question as I am not familiar writing grammars, but first i will have to search how to write a simple grammar. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vini If you need a hand getting started, I've setup a chat with a simple grammar that get's you most of the way: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/101258/room-for-rob-and-vini

Comment: @rob : thanks a lot for your help :) i will look into it.

Comment: @Vini If you've got a moment, jump into the chat room so I can run you through what's needed, the simple grammar I've written there at least will parse your current input :)

Answer (score 0):

So i could find an approach to achieve my task. I have a list of all available operators and a list of all available operands. The list of operands can be obtained by splitting the formula string based on the operator string.

```
var Operatorlist = new string[] { "Min", "Max", "Abs", "Pow", "+", "-", "*", "/", "(", ")", "²", "³", "Length", " ", "\r", "\n", ",", "[", "]", "Sqrt", "Cubrt", "^" };
string[] formulaSplit = formula.Split(Operatorlist,StringSplitOption.None);
```

Now to parse the formula to get a list of operands and operators

```
string sb="";
var formlist = new list<string>();
foreach(var c in calc.CalculationFormula)
{
    sb = sb + c;
    if(delimstringlist.Contains(sb))
    {
        formlist.Add(sb);
        sb = "";
    }
    else if(formulaSplit.Contains(sb))
    {
        formlist.Add(sb);
        sb = "";
    }

}
```

May not be so efficient, but will surely do the task.